# Changing color and transparency of layer using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, symbology

I would like to create an ArcPy script to change the color and transparency of a collection of layers.

The color and transparency would be based on wildcards such as "*_dog" or "*_chicken".

The layer symbology is "single symbol" and the transparency will be a constant percentage for the color.

The problem I encountered, how do I change the color and transparency of the layer?

I can't find any code samples or documentation to point me in the right direction.

I found a post that suggests this is not possible with ArcPy ... hopefully that's incorrect.

Comment: you can set the transparency of a layer with arcpy: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000008000000

Answer (score 5):

You can't really change the symbology of a layer in arcpy with the level of customization you have when just right clicking a layer and using the symbology menu.  However, you can make a "template" layer that contains the symbology you want and then use `ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (in_layer, in_symbology_layer)`.  This will allow you to apply the symbology for any layer with that of the "template". Then you can use:

```
yourLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r'path to your layer') 
yourLayer.transparency = 50 #as a percentage
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to change the properties of a layer directly. The properties of a layer can be changed, but only by importing properties from another layer in the map or a layer file. Even the layer name cannot be changed without an existing layer or layer file. "[UpdateLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s30000003p000000)" in the ArcGIS Help can give you more details and some examples.